# How to get Email id from FB library

Tags: php, facebook, email

I want to access email id of the user, for that i tried below code, I checked many  sites for this purpose. I found these ways to access user's email id. But none of them seems to work. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('MY_app_id', 'my_app_secret');
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://prov.resolv.com/provision_sid/Facebook_2/fbconfig.php');
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
} catch (Exception $ex) {
}

if (isset($session)) {
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
    $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name');      // To Get Facebook full name
    echo $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email'); 

    die();

    $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
    $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ---- */


    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
}
?>
```

I tried multiple option to request email id

1>   `$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,email');`

2>   `$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me',['fields' => 'id,name,email,address,first_name,last_name']);`

By above request too, I'm not able to get email id of the user.

Is there any other way to request email id of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask for the `email` permission, by using `scope` in the login URL.

SDK version 5:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, array('scope' => 'email'));
```

SDK version 4:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
```

Don't forget to also request the email field:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email');
```

Note: If the user does not agree to share email with your app you will not get it.

Comment: I just tried this option. 
It say **Sorry, this page isn't available**.

[URL](https://www.facebook.com/Array/dialog/oauth?client_id=992386390895878&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprov.resolv.com%2Fprovision_sid%2FFacebook_2%2Ffbconfig.php&state=4410974b8fc3d405243a76d3bbd62f29&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.15) generated

Comment: Do you have the correct redirect URL set up in your app?

Comment: you always had to ask for the email permission in the scope, that´s not what changed. what changed is declarative fields. you should update the answer, it is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you @luschn, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes the redirect url is correct, before adding this scope url was working fine. [Url](https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=992386390895878&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprov.resolv.com%2Fprovision_sid%2FFacebook_2%2Ffbconfig.php&state=ad6f711f5211388b249d7be2c59b24ea&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.15) generate before.

Comment: @Shubham, I see you use an older version of the facebook SDK (4), and this one has a different syntax. Just use it like this: `$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));`

Comment: @moni_dragu this time URL worked, but still no email id. This time it asked for email id while login on facebook.

I'm using `$graphObject->getProperty('email');` to get email  id. Is this the correct way to get email id ?

Comment: `$graphObject->getProperty('email');` should work fine. Just be sure you request email field: `$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email');` Please note that if the user does not agree to share email with your app you will not get it.

Answer (score 1):

As per Facebook Policy, if User has kept Email as a Private then there is no way to get that else you can have it using following line.

`$helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, array('scope' => 'email'));`

Comment: URL generated by this is not working.
Base url is generated is **https://www.facebook.com/Array/dialog/oauth**, which is not there on facebook server.

Before adding this, base url is **https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth**, which is working fine.

Comment: To be a safer side, just make sure that your Email is public in Facebook Account.

For your reference, see this.
http://prntscr.com/cqglbr

Comment: Yes the user's email has to be public. You can write an extra if condition that if the email isn't there then present the user with a text field to enter his email address